# Calculation of triangle properties by having side length and angle distributions

Tags: geometry, probability-distributions, triangles, convolution

I am trying to understand, how to calculate properties of a triangle which  has distributions of the side lengths and angles instead of constant values.

Example: triangle ABC with the angle $\alpha$,$\beta$ and $\gamma$ respectively 
 opposite to the sides a, b or c. 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPvyO.png) The distribution of the side length a and b as well as the distribution of the angle $\gamma$ (P(a), P(b), P($\gamma$)) are given:
\begin{align}
P(a) &\approx \exp(-{10 \times (a-1)^2})  \\
P(b) &\approx \exp(-20 \times (b-3)^2) \\
P(\gamma) &\approx \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $\gamma\in \left[\frac{pi}{3},\frac{2\pi}{3}\right]$, and} \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

What would be the distribution of the length of the side c (P(c))?

As far as I understand, using convolution of two probability distributions corresponds to the additions of the variables. But I am not sure, how to use e.g. the law of cosines with distributions.

Comment: I don't understand the last one---do you mean $P(\lambda)$?  Or is the $\lambda$ on the right meant to be a $\gamma$?  What is $P(c)$?

Comment: @XanderHenderson : I have modified the question (and corrected the error), hopefully it is now more clear.

Comment: Do the distributions $P(a)$ and $P(b)$ written as Gaussians mean you care only about the intervals around $a = 1$ and $b=3$? In order to have $a$ and $b$ as two sides of a triangle, they must be positive, so either you are asking only for an approximation in the region of interest, or you should allow truncation or modification of the tails.